# Java - connection timed out for a URL which is accessed from OS

Tags: java

we've implemented Google translate API using the secured HTTP URL. This started giving the connection timedout error. The same URL is accessible using WGET command in LINUX. Hence the problem is not related to Firewall or network. It's related to the Java layer.

Here the sample URL (This won't work as I've given the invalid key in the URL now but URL works fine with valid key id)
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=ingenier%C3%ADa+de+minas&key=sdfdf&source=es&target=en&userip=192.168.1.99

We've also installed the security certificates to see if that solves the problme. But no luck

The same functionaltiy works fine on our test environment and the problem is only with production server.

I've also used "-Djavax.net.debug=all" system parameter to debug further. In the production, it's failed when it gets connecting to Google server.

Not really sure what the issue here but any help would be appreciated.

**Modified:**
Adding exception log...
Here the stacktrace when HTTPS URL is being accessed

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:564)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at WGET.main(WGET.java:13)
```

Here the stacktrace when HTTP URL is being accessed

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:234)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at WGET1.main(WGET1.java:13)
```

Comment: just to separate out, have you tried hitting any `HTTP` URL (without secure) and see if it's the `HTTPS` URLs that are causing the timeout? Also, providing the complete exception stacktrace or error info in the question will better help understand the problem.

Comment: If the same code works in test but not production, then the problem is likely to be a configuration issue. Looking at the URL you've pasted, userip is a private address and will be meaningless outside of your network, could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Hi Asgs - I've just tried using HTTP and seems to be the same problem. But originally if we try this service with http, it should send the error back saying, service shoudl be used via secured layer. I'll amend the quesiton with exception details in few minutes

Comment: Have you configured any proxy for your JVM, which might be causing the problem? Also, how do you access this URL from your application. Is it using HTTPURLConnection or some other way?

Comment: Hi Romski - yep, we initially thought the same and trying to check the configuration etc. But as far as we know, we're sure configurations are equal. Yes, you're right - end user id is doesn't really matter but that's just the parameter which shouldn't have impacted

Comment: Hi Ankit - no, we don't have any proxy configured for JVM. And the application is accessing the HttpURLConnection i.e.; HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

Comment: Perhaps lack of a proxy on the jvm is a problem? Wget uses system settings for proxy.